# Inappropriate Humor Term

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a term I've been trying to remember that defines a moment where a serious story or scene ends with a joke or light ending.  We see it in TV shows like Star Trek (TOS) where an otherwise grim story has been ended with a joke.

The term could be psycho-analytical.  It's possibly German in origin, but that may not be accurate.

It isn't schadenfreude, macabre, dark humor, black humor, black comedy.  It's a term meant to signify the writer's apparent idiosyncratic need to end a dark/grim story with a joke.

Writers of Star Trek were known for this.  So is Joss Whedon.

This is not necessarily a form "bad" writing.  But it Is considered inappropriate.

Comment: Something like *denouement*, but for a dark-to-light instead of an intense-to-peaceful transition?

Comment: Are you looking for *paraprosdokian*? But that's not really relevant to shows or scenes, mainly to the written or spoken word.

Comment: Does [comic relief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_relief) work? It often happens in the middle of a story, but might apply here.

Comment: What makes you thing it's inappropriate? The examples you give don't sound inappropriate, and I've not heard people complain about them. There are various terms for this (stinger, tag, sign-off...), but none convey the sense of inappropriateness. In terms of screenwriting, there are various subtypes depending on whether it's a sitcom (with a sentimental moment followed by a joke) or a drama, it's before or after the end-credits, it relates to the plot or is totally irrelevant, it's the same every week, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It can be described as **comic relief**:

> comic episodes in a dramatic or literary work that offset more serious sections.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries/Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/comic_relief)

Note that comic relief is considered a legitimate literary technique, although (like anything) it can be misused.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_relief).

Comment: Nope. It's a single-word term.

Answer (score 0):

*defuse*

> **1** to improve a difficult or dangerous situation, for example by making people less angry or by dealing with the causes of a problem
>   ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/defuse))
>   
>   **1.1** Make (a situation) less tense or dangerous.
>   ‘*With a joke and a smile he was able to defuse many a tense situation and his presence in any room was unmistakable.*’
>   ([lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/defuse))

Comment: It's not really inappropriate, though at first it may appear inappropriate or even insensitive. It's intended to provide a relief from the tension built up and may also be a kind of sarcasm  on the preceding grimness.

Comment: Sorry, no. It's a single-word term that's not a common word.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Juxtaposed humour?

Like you got the contrast between something very serious vs something laughable placed side-by-side, and there is stark difference between the two.

Comment: Nope. It's a single-word term.

Answer (score 0):

“Facetious” or “crass” is likely the word you are looking for, yes?

Do PLEASE Let me know. It eats at me when I can’t think of a word even if it’s to help someone else so I’ll be running through possibilities for weeks.  Thanks

Edit: If that’s not it can you clarify if the word is used by the person telling The joke such as “I was being facetious” or is it said by the people that have to hear it like “that joke he said was very dark, crass sense of humor and that will help me narrow down further the possibilities for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bathos)' rather broad definition of **bathos** covers this:

> *bathos* [noun; non-count]: In literary criticism, bathos is a sudden change in speech or writing from a serious or important subject to a
> ridiculous or very ordinary one.

So, selecting the relevant subsense licensed:

- a sudden change in speech or writing from a serious subject to an [in context]
  ridiculous one. Inappropriate levity.